# iOS Push notifications failing on Azure app

Tags: ios, azure, asp.net-web-api

i have a ASP.NET Web API hosted as app on Azure and one of the APIs is to send notifications to users on iOS.

i am facing a strange issue on Azure. Sometimes the push notifications work and randomly stop after. I am using PushSharp and not NotificationHub or anything.

the code basically loops over device tokens and makes calls to APNS.

this seems to work fine locally but fails on Azure.

any ideas what i am missing? the error just says multiple errors.

thanks in advance.

```
var broker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
            broker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, exception) =>
            {
                callback(new Result { status = "FAIL", message = exception.Message });
                Console.WriteLine("failed");
            };
            broker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
            {
                callback(new Result { status = "Success", message = "" });
                Console.WriteLine("pass");
            };
            broker.Start();

            broker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
            {
                DeviceToken = userDeviceToken,
                Payload = JObject.Parse("{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"" + message + "\", \"sound\":\"default\", \"badge\":0 },\"notification\":" + json + " }")
            });


            broker.Stop();
```

Comment: Where does the error show up? Is it in the UI or in an exception catch block or returned from the APNS server?

Comment: please refer to the code above, the error comes up in broker.OnNotificationFailed. any ideas?